# how to implement CURL cli using python to consume REST services

Tags: python, json, rest, curl

There are lot of questions posted how to consume the REST services with python, but none of them worked for me, 
currently with the below curl cli i can get the authentication token.

curl cli

```
curl -v --user username:pass1234 -H "content-type: application/json" -X POST -d "" https://mywebsite/api/v1/auth/token-services --insecure
```

when i execute the above cli i get the json response as below :

output snip from above curl cli

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.4.2
< Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 23:22:41 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 201
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection #0 to host <ipaddress> left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"kind": "object#auth-token", "expiry-time": "Mon Apr 14 23:37:41 2014", "token-id": "l3CvWcEr5rKvooOaCymFvy2qp3cY18XCs4JrW4EvPww=", "link": "https://mywebsite/api/v1/auth/token-services/1634484805"}
```

NOW MY QUESTION is, how to achieve this using python. WHAT libraries i should use? i need to extract the token-id from the json response. so that i will use that token for further request to consume REST services.

if some one can post the PYTHON code snippet for this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for what i am looking for...

Complete Sample code ...

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

token = ""


def get_token(username, password, url):
    global token

    #verify=False will not verify the ssl 
    resp = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False)

    print "\n", dir(resp)
    print "Status Code:", resp.status_code, "\n"
    print "text:", resp.text, "\n"
    print "json:", resp.json(), "\n"
    print "Content:", resp.content, "\n"
    print "Headers:", resp.headers, "\n"
    print "Header(Content-type:)", resp.headers.get('content-type'), "\n"
    print "Header(Content-length:)", resp.headers.get('content-length'), "\n"
    print "OK:", resp.ok, "\n"
    print "json dump:", json.dumps(resp.json())

    json_dict = json.loads(resp.text)

    token = json_dict['token-id']
    print "\ntoken-id:", json_dict['token-id']

    for key, value in json_dict.items():
        print key, "=>", value

    return token    


def get_global_users(token):
    print "\nexecuting get_global_users.."
    print "Token", token
    url = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/global/users'
    headers_dict = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': token}
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers_dict, verify=False)
    print "Status Code:", resp.status_code, "\n"
    print "text:", resp.text, "\n"
    print "json:", resp.json(), "\n"
    json_users = json.loads(resp.text)
    print "all users:\n", json_users['users']

    print "\n"
    for users in json_users['users']:
        for key, value in users.items():
            print key, "=>", value


def post_global_user(token):
    print "\nexecuting post_global_users.."
    print "Token:", token
    url = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/global/users'
    headers_dict = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': token}
    payload = {'username': 'myuser', 'password': 'pas1234', 'pw-type': 0, 'privilege': 15}
    resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers_dict, verify=False)
    print "Status Code:", resp.status_code, "\n"
```

Comment: use `resp.json()` instead of `json.loads(resp.text)` that might produce wrong result due to the wrong character encoding detection sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following HOWTO of the python documentation: [HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html). There you also find a section with an code example for [Basic authentication](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#id6). The HOWTO describes how you can use the module [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

Other useful libraries:

- [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)
- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: thanks for the above references. I used requests module for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

To emulate the curl command:

```
$ curl -v --user username:pass1234 -H "accept: application/json" \
    -X POST -d "" https://mywebsite/api/v1/auth/token-services --insecure
```

in Python using only stdlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import base64
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request

credentials = base64.b64encode(b'username:pass1234')
headers={'Authorization': b'Basic ' + credentials,
         'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = urlopen(Request("https://example.com/post", b"", headers))
data = json.load(response)
token_id = data["token-id"]
```

If you want to see what is sent to/received from a server for https requests; enable debugging:

```
import urllib2

urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1)))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i couldn't get curl cli to emulate in urllib2, so i used requests. I will try above example and will see how it works.